# Book With List of Horror/Monster Movies Published in late 70s/early 80s

Tags: story-identification

I am looking for a book title that had a comprehensive list of horror/monster movies that was published in the late 1970s or early 1980s.

The book was thick, trade paperback size, and contained black and white pictures of some of the movies. (For example, there was a page with a picture from Jason and the Argonauts).

It had movies like the Abominable Dr. Phibes, Frankenstein, Dracula, King Kong, etc.  I believe it was more than just a list of movies, but it didn't have paragraphs and paragraphs about any particular movie, but I recall it being comprehensive at the time.

Comment: I don't have the book with me at the moment so I can't verify this until later today but there is a good chance you are thinking of Dance Macabre by Stephen King. It came out in the early 1980's if I recall and is a history of horror movies and stories stretching back all the way to the 1950's and before. There is a long section dedicated to the 1960's and 1970's and there are occasional black and white pictures inside (again, if I recall correctly). There are multiple places where lists of movies and books are provided, although it's not a decade by decade breakdown. It's a great book.

Comment: I'm going to spam the comment section since I don't feel confident enough in my thinking to make this an answer. I just flipped through the book real quick and as I remembered there are many black and white pictures of movies like the stepford wives, the thing, invasion of the body snatchers, night of the living dead, etc. The book was published in 1981, and is about 400 pages long. However I don't see a picture of Jason and the Argonauts anywhere, and I don't have the time to do a thorough search for specific mentions of movies but I'm pretty sure all the ones you mentioned are in the book.

Comment: @user251563 that's the first thing I thought of as well. But there are many books on the subject.

Answer (score 3):

There are a few different options that I can find (There are more, but many were published after the stated date.

[*The Encyclopedia of Horror Movies: The complete reference*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0060961465)

Sample page:

[image]

[*A Pictorial History of Horror Movies*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/2570440-a-pictorial-history-of-horror-movies) (Less likely, as this is a hardback)

Sample Page:

[image]

And also, the one mentioned in comments, [Danse Macabre](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Danse_Macabre_(book)).

Answer (score 2):

How about this one?

[The Great Book of Movie Monsters (1985)](https://www.amazon.ca/gp/product/0809255251/ref=oh_aui_detailpage_o00_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1)

Comment: Welcome to [scifi.se]! Please add some explanation why you think this is the book in question (e.g. can you confirm that it contains some of the mentioned movies?).

Answer (score 0):

[The Psychotronic Encyclopedia of Film](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/034534345X) was another popular reference work of the time, though it first came around a bit later in the 80s.